# How can I get the full path of a relative directory in Bash?

Tags: bash, directory

Let's say I have a variable like this:

```
directory="/home/lrh/package1/util/../.."
```

How could I convert it to the following?:

```
"/home/lrh"
```

In other words, how could I have Bash "evaluate" the `directory` variable and get the full path?

Comment: Yes, I agree. I just found it.

Answer (score 0):

Changing to the directory seems to be a straightforward approach:

```
echo "$(cd "${directory}"; pwd)"
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is :

```
readlink -f "$directory"
```

(readlink: `print resolved symbolic links or canonical file names`)